# Guess the word game - this is more advanced game than others

Tags: python

I am a beginner at python programming. I am trying to make a game, which will asked you how many numbers of letters of hint you want. Then it will ask you number of lives you want. Then it will give a hint, and ask you to guess a number and type any one letter of your word.

For example, if your word is ***for*** and you type **O** it will show --.o.-- and then if you type ***f*** it will show F.O.--. So I am not able to finish my project.

This is my code:

```
import random 
allthewords =['ability','absence','academy','account','accused','achieve','acquire','address','advance','adverse','advised','adviser','against','airline','airport','another','ancient','auction',
'average','backing','balance','article','barrier','capable','banking','bedroom','caliber','capital','bearing','beating','calling','captain','battery','because','anxious']

random =(random.randrange(0,len(allthewords)))

randomwords = (allthewords[random])
letters=(len(randomwords))

hintnum=input("how many number of letter you want the hint of? ("+str(letters)+" is maximum): ")
hint= ''.join(randomwords)
hint1= hint[0:int(hintnum)]

while hintnum > str(letters):
    print("sorry "+str(letters)+" is maximum")
    hintnum=input("how many number of letter you want the hint of? ("+str(letters)+" is maximum): ")
    print("                                     ")
    hint= ''.join(randomwords)
    hint1= hint[0:int(hintnum)]
    print("                                     ")

l= input("how many number many lives you want?:  ")
lives = l
live = 1
print("hint: " +hint1 + " is in the word")

x=1
place= -1


while x==1:
    user =input("whats your letter?: ")
    print("hint: " +hint1 + " is in the word")
    if 1 != 3:
        place1=place+1
    
    if place == user.find(user):
            print("                        ")
            empty=("_."*letters)
            empty = empty[:place] + user + empty[place+1:]
            print (empty)
            print("its correct")
       ############## 
    if user != randomwords[place+1]:
        lives=int(1)-1
        print("wrong answer try again!")
        print("                                ") 
    if live == 0:
        print("you lost!, too many tries ")
        x= x-1
        a=input("do you want to know the answer?: yes/no")

        if a==("yes"):
            print(randomwords)
        if a==("no"):
            print("ok,thanks")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/354577)

Comment: And be _patient_. You just asked 15 minutes ago. It can take time to get answers here. We're mostly volunteers. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main things I noticed:

- The `lives` input is a string, so convert it to an int first
- In the `place` calculation, each letter takes two spaces
- When inserting `user` in the empty string, remove two characters to compensate for the `user` character
- Avoid using single letter `l` (L) as a variable. It looks like the number `1` which caused some typos in your code
- Some of the words have repeated letters so only the first letter instance will be found
- Set a variable to maintain the current state of the guess word so each correct guessed letter fills in a blank

This code seems to work correctly:

```
import random 
allthewords =['ability','absence','academy','account','accused','achieve','acquire','address','advance','adverse','advised','adviser','against','airline','airport','another','ancient','auction',
'average','backing','balance','article','barrier','capable','banking','bedroom','caliber','capital','bearing','beating','calling','captain','battery','because','anxious']

random =(random.randrange(0,len(allthewords)))

randomwords = (allthewords[random])
letters=(len(randomwords))
print(randomwords)  # for testing

hintnum=input("how many number of letter you want the hint of? ("+str(letters)+" is maximum): ")
hint= ''.join(randomwords)
hint1= hint[0:int(hintnum)]

while hintnum > str(letters):
    print("sorry "+str(letters)+" is maximum")
    hintnum=input("how many number of letter you want the hint of? ("+str(letters)+" is maximum): ")
    print("                                     ")
    hint= ''.join(randomwords)
    hint1= hint[0:int(hintnum)]
    print("                                     ")

l= input("how many number many lives you want?:  ")
lives = int(l)
live = 1
print("hint: " +hint1 + " is in the word")

x=1
place= -1

wordstate = " "*len(randomwords) # start all blank
while x==1:
    user =input("whats your letter?: ")
    print("hint: " +hint1 + " is in the word")
    
    # find letter in word with blank in wordstate
    for i in range(len(wordstate)):
       if wordstate[i] == " " and randomwords[i] == user: # letter found
           wordstate = wordstate[:i] + user + wordstate[i+1:]  # udpate display word
           print('.'.join(wordstate.replace(" ","_"))) # print word with periods
           print("its correct")
           if wordstate.find(' ') == -1: # no spaces remaining, word done
              print("You win!")
              exit()
           break  # found letter
       ############## 
    if not user in randomwords:
        lives=lives-1
        print("wrong answer try again!")
        print("                                ") 
    if lives == 0:
        print("you lost!, too many tries ")
        x= x-1
        a=input("do you want to know the answer?: yes/no")

        if a==("yes"):
            print(randomwords)
        if a==("no"):
            print("ok,thanks")
```

Comment: but there is a problem it erases the previous letters and print the new letters. i want the previous letters to stay. Sir please help

Comment: Answer updated to retain letters